# Get current system time in milliseconds

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, what is the right way to get the current system time since epoch(1970) in **milliseconds**?

I tried `Time.now.to_i` , it seems not the result I want. I need the result shows milliseconds and with `long` type, not `float` or `double`.

Answer (score 10):

```
(Time.now.to_f * 1000).to_i
```

`Time.now.to_f` shows you the time including decimal numbers. To get number of miliseconds just multiply the time by 1000.

Answer (score 7):

You can combine [`to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Time.html#method-i-to_i) and [`usec`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Time.html#method-i-usec). The former returns the number of seconds since the Epoch, the latter returns the number of microseconds:

```
require 'time'
t = Time.at(1473152006, 2000)

t.to_i * 1000 + t.usec / 1000
#=> 1473152006002
```

This is equivalent to:

```
t.strftime('%s%L')
#=> "1473152006002"
```

In some cases like the above, `to_f` would introduce a slight floating point error:

```
t.to_f * 1000
#=> 1473152006001.9998
(t.to_f * 1000).to_i
#=> 1473152006001
```

Comment: You can fix the floating point by rounding the value. That will also convert the float value to int. `(Time.now.to_f * 1000).round`

Comment: @kallax that would fail for `Time.at(1473152006, 999)`